# Get access to data for campaigns created by expert outside my company using Google Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have a company which does music promotion and we are working with Google Ads experts to run campaigns for us on some Youtube Videos.
We are currently tracking all the Youtube stats like comments, views, likes and etc... using the Youtube API.
But we would also like to track data from the Google Ads API like campaign_budget, click_views etc...

What would be the best way to do so.

Should I create a manager account and invite the google ads expert

or
Should he invite me as a client ?
In this case how could he give me a token that only works for my campaigns and not for the campaigns of other of its clients ?

Thanks

Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

He should be running your campaigns in it's own account (if not then there's something dodgy going on!)

If that's the case he'll be able to invite you to the account, and then you'll be able to authorise the api access with your own Google account

Comment: Hi thanks, the fact is that in order to get the API key i need to be a manager. So if he is the manager and invite me as a client. I won't be able to get the key. Only he can get it.

Comment: You can still authenticate the API without having manager access. You can authenticate the API using a Google account with standard or read-only access to the Ads account.

I'd recommend using a service account that is authorised by your own account. There is some good info on that in the Google Ads API documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts

Comment: Thank you so much man. I finally figure it out !!! Thanks to you